# Convergence of fixed points

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

Problem: Let $f_t$ and $f_0$ be continuous functions where $f_t,f_0:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ and $t \in [0,1]$. Suppose that $f_0$ has a unique fixed point $x_0$ and $f_t$ has a unique fixed point $x_t$. If $f_t \to f_0$ uniformly on $[0,\infty)$ as $t \to 0$, is it true that $x_t \to x_0$?

My attempt: Define $f_t = tx$ then each $f_t$ has a unique fixed point at $0$. However, $f_1$ has infinitely many fixed points. This is where I'm having troubles with. Is there any hint or suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
Suppose $f_0$ has a graph that looks like this (with $y=x$ in blue):

[image]

Let $f_t$ be obtained by moving this graph slightly up on the left and slightly down on the right.

Answer (score 3):

First you should note that for convergence you only need almost all elements of the series not all, that is your f_1 should not give you any troubles. I would suggest that you do not try to define a specific function right away, but get a good grasp of how a function must look like and draw one. Therefore note that the fixed points are precisely the intersections with the line f(x)=x and that a counterexample for f_0 must have infinite points that are almost fixed points. At the end, if you want an explicit set of functions you should be able to define them easily.